# List all files in a directory recursively but exclude directories themselves

Tags: linux, find, search, file-search

Simple question, I'm running the following find command:

```
find . -type d \( -path ./.git -o   \
                  -path ./log -o    \
                  -path ./public -o \
                  -path ./tmp       \) \
                  -prune -o         \
                  -print
```

To list all the files in my directory, excluding the specified directories.

This works great, however, what I want to also do is exclude any actual directories from the output, so if there is a directory structure as follows:

```
test
  -- foo.text
  -- bar.text
```

when I run my command I'd like to see:

```
./test/foo.text
./test/bar.text
```

instead of:

```
.
./test
./test/foo.text
./test/bar.text
```

Can anybody help?

Comment: Title does not match content.

Answer (score 16):

```
find . -type f
```

will do it.  You can do exec if you want to operate on file names.

Comment: yes, but I need to exclude all files under certain directories.

Comment: `-type f` is for _regular_ files. _directories_ and _regular files_ are 2 of many different types of files on Unix. With `-type f`, you're excluding directories, but also all the other types of files like symlinks, sockets, fifos, devices, doors...

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas, *doors*?

Comment: @user1717828, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doors_%28computing%29

Answer (score 7):

Just use `! -type d`:

```
find . -type d \( -path ./.git -o \
                  -path ./log -o \
                  -path ./public -o \
                  -path ./tmp \) -prune -o \
       ! -type d -print
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way to do it. I'm piping your output from `find` (using `xargs`) to a little bit of bash which asks the question "Is this not a directory?" and if it's not, it echoes it to your terminal.

Here's the whole she-bang:

`find . -type d \( -path ./.git -o -path ./log -o -path ./public -o -path ./tmp \) -prune -o -print | xargs -i bash -c 'if [ ! -d "{}" ]; then echo "{}"; fi'`

Here's just my addition:

`xargs -i bash -c 'if [ ! -d "{}" ]; then echo "{}"; fi'`

To explain:

`xargs -i` replace string "{}" with arguments (those that are piped in)

`bash -c` commands read from string

`if [ ! -d "{}"];` is this a directory.

`echo "{}"` echo the find result.

`fi;` finish if.

Comment: There, you're turning the filename into shell code. Typical privilege escalation path. As one can create a file called `$(do-what-I-want)` for instance to have _you_ do what he wants.

Comment: This is a cool workaround when one not knowing how to use `-o ! -type d`. Cool trick!